# UWP: Xamarin Forms Tabbed Page changing page doesn't call OnAppearing

Tags: tabs, uwp, xamarin.forms, tabbedpage

In a Xamarin Forms project, I have created a TabbedPage inside which I have added 5 child navigation pages.

```
{
    Children.Add(new NavigationPage(new A()));
    Children.Add(new NavigationPage(new B()));
    Children.Add(new NavigationPage(new C()));
    Children.Add(new NavigationPage(new D()));
    Children.Add(new NavigationPage(new E()));
}
```

When I click manually on a tab B from Tab A; B's OnAppearing method is called as expected. However when I programmatically change the tab using

```
tabbedPage.CurrentPage = tabbedPage.Children[index]
```

Then B's OnAppearing method is called never. This is happening on UWP.

Comment: Seems like i have simillar problem, are your viewmodel on each page execute non-local data?

Comment: For this we haven't use MVVM, we are just simply using MVC. When we manually change the tab the onappearing method of selected tab is being called however when we programmatically change the tab then onappearing method is not called for the selected tab

Comment: I have placed this line code (`this.CurrentPage = this.Children[2];`) in the `TabbedPage`  constructor method. But I could not reproduce your issue in my side. This is my [code sample](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/TabbedPagedTest.git). Please check.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Thanks, Your code is working in that scenario. On App launch it selects the Third page and calls its OnAppearing. However I modified your code to replicate my scenario. On First page There is a button "Click Me" I put code to show the Third page on this button click. On click of the button user is redirected on Third page from First, but the OnAppearing() method of Third is not being called at all. Please check. (Let me know if I can commit my changes on your repo for you to test)

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Did you get a chance to look for the issue?

Answer (score 1):

As of Xamarin Forms 3.4.0.1008975 and UWP 6.1.5 this still appears to be an issue. I solved it like this:

Make an interface called IAppearable:

```
internal interface IAppearable
{
    void HandleAppearing();
}
```

Have your content page implement this interface:

```
public partial class MyContentPage : ContentPage, IAppearable
```

In HandleAppearing do what you would have done in OnAppearing:

```
public void HandleAppearing()
    {
        // do appearing stuff here
    }
```

After you programmatically set your tab page use this code:

```
CurrentPage = Children[pageIndex];

if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.UWP)
{
    if (CurrentPage is IAppearable appearablePage)
    {
        appearablePage.HandleAppearing();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have this problem with XF v4.0. Do you have a link to the reported bug?

Comment: Same here in july 2019. Any reported bug?

Comment: This is still a thing in 2021. Issue is created https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/3855 just seems hard to fix on Xamarin side. Nevertheless, @kip-morgan approach seems the best one here. Only question is, who should be responsible for triggering `HandleAppearing()`. In my case I did it in `OnCurrentPageChanged`.